# Self-Signed CA not trusted in iOS 13 anymore

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl

I created a Self-Signed CA and trust this certificate in Settings and it's working well in iOS 12. But after I upgrade the iOS version to 13, even the certificate trusted in Setting but still can't get it to working. So how do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe your certificate is expired

Comment: @zylenv I just checked. It's not expired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is known about your certificate but it might be that it is not meeting the new requirements introduced in iOS 13. [Requirements for trusted certificates in iOS 13 and macOS 10.15](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176) describes these and these include that RSA keys must be at least 2048 bits and it is no longer possible to use SHA-1 as signature algorithm.

Comment: It seems the server certificate not meet the requirements. We fixed it, and now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: We have been trying to generate a self-signed certificate and get it onto an ipad (iOS 13).  No matter what we try the certificate will not be accepted by the ipad without displaying "Not Trusted". 

@yongho is there any possibility you could list out the specific steps you went to create the certificate?

Comment: Very useful information. Unlike iOS 13.1.3 behavior of allowing addition unsupported certificates to trusted, showing them in green as accepted, but then not accepting in Mail and Safari.

Comment: @TonyJWatson You have to make sure the certificate meets the iOS 13 requirements. You can find out the requirement information on apple developer website. The certificate used to be working on iOS 12, maybe it will not work on iOS 13.

Comment: I follow all instructions in this requirements but what ever combination I made safari on iOS mark my certificate as not trusted. It works on windows ie, chrome and firefox and on linux chrome and firefox, android also but on iOS does not. :(

Comment: Make a demo with objc/swift and python https server https://github.com/c0i/https-server-client-ios.git

Answer (score 1):

I Happen to try something and it actually worked, Send the self signed .cer to the iphone with another configured email. The cert will be added to the iphone cert store. And Go to general setting then find Profil. Within the option you will see the name of the cert you just added and the option to configure it. Just do that in first place. Once done. Add the Exchange email account just like any other, it will prompt with certificate error but you will the option to continue and the account will be added correctly. I tried on Iphone 11 in the Mail App with Latest IOS.